# Matebook 14 2020 integrated speakers too loud (even at volume 1)

Tags: audio, speakers

The integrated speakers of my Matebook 14 AMD 2020 are too loud - even if turned down to 1. All required drivers are installed (using Huawei PC Manager). There are no loudness settings in the device manager i could deactivate. It does not make a difference if running Windows 10 or 11.

The device manager shows 4 audio devices (AMD Audio Device, AMD High Definition Audio Device, Everest I2S Codec Audio Device and Nihimic mirroring device).

I did a comparison with my desktop computer using a 440Hz test tone. I used a sound analyzer app on my tablet to 'measure' the loudness of each (I matched them at a volume level of 15):

| Windows volume level | Matebook | PC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 63db | 63dB |
| 10 | 62dB | 57dB |
| 5 | 59dB | 47dB |
| 1 | 52dB | 37dB |

The ambient noise was about 35dB. You see that even with the volume down to 1 the Matebook is louder than the pc at level 5.

Can anyone with an AMD Matebook confirm this behaviour? Or even better is there any tweak (maybe something like a registry setting) to turn down the volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem was caused by the driver for the Everest I2S Codec.
Version 1.0.3.6 was installed and after updating to 2.0.4.9 (found at [www.catalog.update.microsoft.com](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com)) the volume control now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this answer. Indeed this solves the problem.
I even visited Huawei Service Center in Warsaw with that problem but the service engineer said that it is normal for this model.

It is not normal, updating the driver solves the issue and now the volume scale is proper.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1110942)